# What could be a suitable UI element for map radius?

Tags: android

The android app that I am building contains a map activity. In that activity I need the user to specify a circle around its location.

And the radius of this circle needs to be provided by user. So what could be the best UI element to let the user specify the radius.

Best option that comes to my mind is a seek bar. One sliding it to one end, radius increases and vice versa.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The circle which you had in your screenshot, and allow the user to zoom in and out, so that the area covered by the circle changes.

Comment: No, zooming in- zoom out should not change the radius in a absolute sense. For eg: if the user is standing at a point A and has asked for a radius of 1 mile. The radius of circle should remain 1 mile, irrespective of the zoom level of the map. Yes, the size of the circle would vary in relation to the scale of the map which will change whenever user zooms in zooms out. But the actual terrain that the circle spreads over would remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. A plus and minus button (like google maps has for zooming)
2. A gesture (2 finger to the edges of the screen for increasing the size e.g.) [**no real UI element, but maybe more user-friendly**]
3. A vertical or horizontal slider

Comment: slider would take a lot of space and then I will have to calibrate it as well. So option 1 is definitely a better option than this. However, I am still not clear about option 2. If I got this correct, wouldn't this clash with google map's zoom in and zoom out gesture?

Comment: Yeah, about the slider you are right. But you may could implement a "slider gesture", like swiping from left to right on the bottom of the screen increases the size and swiping from right to left decreases it. This wouldn't interfere with googles map zom gesture I think.

Comment: But for this horizontal gesture, I guess it would need to be done outside the map. Otherwise it would result in the map moving in the direction opposite to the gesture.